# 'failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established' on Xcode simulator only

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, websocket, capacitor

I'm trying to build my Ionic application on iOS. I ran the command:

`ionic capacitor run ios --prod`

Besides the WebSocket failure, the application runs fine on my simulator upon building and running. API requests go through, navigation and functionalities are as expected. The WebSocket error I'm getting is:

```
capacitor://localhost/main-es2015.f58236827f7cb117f182.js

WebSocket connection to 'wss://API_URL/cable?token=<token>' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

To add, the previous iteration of my application which is currently released on the App Store is working just fine and is not encountering the WebSocket connectivity failure. **Seems as if the issue is isolated to Xcode / Xcode's simulator**, which, of course, I have to fix before proceeding to release a new update to the App Store.

Are there any configurations for me to consider checking? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

`Ionic: 6.20.1`
`Xcode: 15.2 (15C500b)`
`MacOS: Sonoma 14.3`
`Simulator iOS ver: 15.0`

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y83eL.png)

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the application, and changing the Simulator's iOS versions to different ones. I've also set **App Transport Security Settings > Allow Arbitrary Loads > YES** in my info.plist. However, it still returned the same logs.

**UPDATE:** Tried running the application on my personal device and it behaves as intended, flow is smooth and does not encounter the issues caused by the WebSocket connectivity failure. This confirms my previous theory that it's just isolated to the Xcode simulator. Such weird behavior, any leads would still be appreciated!